# Changing the background color of a active method and property in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors, background

I'm currently looking after a way to change the background color that appears on an active (same position as cursor/caret) on methods and properties like these:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jRb1.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEQWJ.png]

I have tried to search for this, but can't seem to find the right term of how to search for this.

**EDIT:** I found the answer as going into Preferences -> General -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Occurrences

Comment: Humanoidism, could you add an answer with the solution you added in your question and mark it as solved? In this way, it'll be more readable and question will be properly answered.

Comment: My reputation does not allow to answer my own questions before after 8 hours. I will post an answer at that moment :-)